# How to set custom setter for property in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How do I define setter for schema property after I have defended schema like

```
var User = new Schema({email:String})
```

How do I define setter for that `email` property like:

```
User.email.setter(function ...)
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. Custom properties can be set like

```
User.path("email", {
    set: function(email) {
        return email
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For those arriving here looking for custom setters, the docs are curiously silent about this but it is possible using the Schema `set` and `get` properties:

```
mongoose.Schema({ email: { type: String, get: val => `Email me at ${val}` } })
```

If anyone can link me to where in the docs this is covered, I'll happily add the link.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options