# store values in mongoose by removing comma i.e(abc or 233 or 2344 or 20000)?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    data: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Value', schema);
```

If user enter a,b,c then data will be saved in mongoose like this abc or if user enter number 200,000 then it will be saved like this 200000

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512683/how-to-format-data-in-model-before-saving-in-mongoose-expressjs or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532723/how-to-set-custom-setter-for-property-in-mongoose, specifically the `set` function that you can set on the "data" property in your schema. BTW, maybe there's a better word than "data" to describe your property?

Comment: thanks to all , i did it by using get and set function